# K8s Nginx ingress controller costs high CPU usage

Tags: nginx, kubernetes

Using TOP to check the cpu and memory status of K8s cluster host, I found that the CPU cost of Nginx-ingress-controller is always high. If I set the cpu limit to 2, then the CPU time would be almost 200%. If without cpu limit, the CPU time would be almost 400% in a 4-core VM. The nginx ingress controller is 0.8.3.

Is that normal?

Thanks

Liu Peng

Comment: How much traffic does the controller handle?

Comment: Hi, @svenwltr, the traffic is handled by nginx instead of nginx controller. The nginx controller just manage the nginx configuration and processes.

Comment: By the way, the test QPS going through Nginx is about 300~400.